# Pythonのプログラムで name 'MenberID' is not defined エラーになる

Tags: python, python3

制作したPythonのプログラムで少しおかしすぎるエラーが発生しました。
アーチェリー用のプログラムを制作しているのですが、動かそうとすると

```
name 'MenberID' is not defined
```

という少々おかしいエラーが出てきてしまいます。
('MenberID' は変数ではなくリストとして定義したはずなんですけど...)

下のプログラムのコードでどこかおかしいところがあるならば教えてくれると幸いです。

```py
import datetime

def set_up_players() :
    Assignment = True
    Memberlist = []
    MenberID = []
    while Assignment == True :
        print("")
        membership = str(input("Are you assigned already? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' :'"))
        if membership == "Y" :
            y1 = int(input("Enter your year to assign your membership. :"))
            m1 = int(input("Enter your month to assign your membership. :"))
            d1 = int(input("Enter your day to assign your membership. :"))
            dt1 = datetime.datetime(year=y1, month=m1, day=10, hour=d1)
            time = datetime.datetime.now() - dt1
            daytime = int((time.days))
            if daytime > 500 :
                print("You need to renew your membership.")
                print("Go to office to renew you membership card.")
            else :
                print("Welcom back to our Archely club")
        elif membership == "N" :
            check = False
            print("You need to make your membership")
            name = str(input("Enter your name. :"))
            while check == False :
                id = str(input("Enter any 5 digit number :"))
                if (id in MenberID) == True:
                    print ("Sorry it's already in list, Try again.")
                else :
                    check = True
            Memberlist.append(name)
            MenberID.append(id)
        else :
            print("Answer in Y or N.")
        print("")
        Assign = str(input("Finish assignment?? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' : "))
        if Assign == "N" :
            Assignment = True
        elif Assign == "Y" :
            Assignment = False
        else :
            print("Answer in Y or N.")


    return Memberlist,MenberID

def sign_up_players() :
    Playerlist = []
    PlayerID = []
    player_count = 0
    while player_count == 5:
        id = str(input("Enter your  5 digit ID. :"))
        if (id in MenberID) == True:
            name = str(input("Enter your name. :"))
            Playerlist.append(name)
            PlayerID.append(id)
            player_count = player_count + 1
            print(player_count)
        else :
            print("Sorry but Register first.")


    return MenberID,Playerlist,PlayerID #エラーが出たのはここです

def set_score(NoofPlayer) :
    score = []
    counter = NoofPlayer - 1
    for i in range (counter) :
        score.append(0)
    return NoofPlayer, score

def set_values () :
    Memberlist,MenberID = set_up_players()
    MenberID,Playerlist,PlayerID = sign_up_players()
    NoofPlayer = int(len(Playerlist))
    maxshoot = 5
    set_score(NoofPlayer)
    Nooftargets = NoofPlayer
    NoofPG = NoofPlayer
    Round = 5
    Noofarrows = 1*Round*NoofPlayer
    NoofLays = NoofPlayer
    Podium = NoofPlayer
    return Memberlist,MenberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium

def Allocate_Equipment(NoofPlayer) :
    ownarrows = []
    ownbows = []
    ownPG = []
    co = NoofPlayer
    while co > 0 :
        arrows = str(input("Do you have your own arrows? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' :'"))
        if arrows == "Y" :
            ownarrows.append(yes)
        else :
            ownarrows.append(no)
        PG = str(input("Do you have your own PG? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' :'"))
        if PG == "Y" :
            ownPG.append(yes)
        else :
            ownPG.append(no)
        bows = str(input("Do you have your own bow? Answer Y for 'Yes' N for 'No' :'"))
        if bows == "Y" :
            ownbows.append(yes)
        else :
            ownbows.append(no)
        co = co - 1
    print(ownarrows,ownPG,ownbows)

    return NoofPlayer, ownarrows, ownbows, ownPG

def shooting_arrows (Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Round,score) :
    RoundTime = 0
    while Round > RoundTime :
        PlayerShoot = 0
        while PlayerShoot < Round :
            CurrentPlayer = 1
            while NoofPlayer > CurrentPlayer :
                Player_shoot_arrow(Playerlist,CurrentPlayer)
                Updata_score(score,CurrentPlayer,hitplace)
                Displayscore(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,score)
                CurrentPlayer = CurrentPlayer + 1
            PlayerShoot = PlayerShoot + 1
        RoundTime = RoundTime + 1


    return Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Round,score,RoundTime,PlayerShoot,CurrentPlayer

def Player_shoot_arrow(Playerlist,CurrentPlayer) :
    print("It's "  , Playerlist[CurrentPlayer],  "'s turn.")
    hitplace = str(input("Where did you get? :"))
    return Playerlist,CurrentPlayer,hitplace

def Updata_score(score,CurrentPlayer,hitplace) :
    if hitplace == "A":
        score[CurrentPlayer] = score[CurrentPlayer] + 100
    elif hitplace == "B":
        score[CurrentPlayer] = score[CurrentPlayer] + 50
    elif hitplace == "C":
        score[CurrentPlayer] = score[CurrentPlayer] + 10


    return score,CurrentPlayer,hitplace

def Displayscore(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,score) :
    for i in range (NoofPlayer):
        print(Playerlist[NoofPlayer], + "'s score is " , + score[NoofPlayer])

    return Playerlist,NoofPlayer,score

def score_board(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Podium,score) :
    Displayscore(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,score)
    scorelist = []
    scorelist = score
    score.sort(reverse=True)
    Podium = len(score)
    third = score[2]
    second = score[1]
    first = score[0]
    print("Third Player is "  , Playerlist[scorelist.index(third)] ,  "who get " , scorelist[2])
    print("Third Player is "  , Playerlist[scorelist.index(second)] ,  "who get " , scorelist[1])
    print("Third Player is "  , Playerlist[scorelist.index(first)] ,  "who get " , scorelist[0])
    return Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Podium,score,scorelist


Memberlist,MenberID,Playerlist,PlayerID,NoofPlayer,maxshoot,Nooftargets,NoofPG,Round,Noofarrows,NoofLays,Podium = set_values ()
Allocate_Equipment(NoofPlayer)
Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Round,score = shooting_arrows (Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Round,score)
score_board(Playerlist,NoofPlayer,Podium,score)
```

Comment: エラーメッセージにある通り、`sign_up_players` 関数内では `MenberID` 変数が未定義になっていますね。おそらく、`set_up_players` 関数の戻り値である `MenberID` を `sign_up_players` 関数に渡すつもりだったのではないでしょうか。ところで話は変わりますが、`MenberID` は `MemberID` とした方が良いかと思います。

Comment: [名前空間とスコープ](https://codor.co.jp/python/namespace-and-scope), [Pythonのスコープ（グローバル変数とローカル変数）のルール](https://www.headboost.jp/python-scope-global-local-variables/) とか [Python命名規則一覧](https://qiita.com/naomi7325/items/4eb1d2a40277361e898b) を読んで、何処で定義されてどの範囲で使われる変数なのか名前を見れば分かるように工夫すると良いでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

sign_up_players()関数において、MenberIdが未定義かと思います。

どこかに定義すると治ると思います。